# Command 'node' not found, but can be installed with: sudo apt install nodejs

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-18.04, bitnami

I wanted to install bitnami nodejs stack on Ubuntu 18.04. after installing terminal isn't recognizing node command. I even can't check node version.

After installing i have tried to check for node and npm version. But every time I am getting Command 'node' not found, but can be installed with:sudo apt install nodejs. I have already installed nodejs Stack from bitnami. i don't want to install it again. i have tried to setup environment variable through "export PATH=$PATH:/opt/nodejs-10.15.3-2/nodejs/bin" this command. But I can only check nodejs version only once per session. I mean if I close terminal then I can't check nodejs version. so I can't use Visual studio code as node is not recognized.

Comment: You can link the node binary to your global bin directory like this `ln -s /opt/nodejs-10.15.3-2/nodejs/bin/node /bin/node`. Alternatively, you can put the export statement in `.bashrc` or `/etc/profile` (that's the preffered method)

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here. Once you install a Bitnami stack, you need to load the Bitnami environment to use the different components that the stack installs. You can use the Bitnami Console to do so, please run these commands

```
cd installdir
./use_APPNAME
```

> APPNAME is the name of the stack you installed

You can find more information in our documentation: https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/how-to/understand-bnconsole/